# Ubuntu using Linux Subsystem for Windows .sh problem

Tags: permissions, scripts, windows-10

I'm trying to run a .sh script in my home directory and I get the following error.

```
-bash: ./test.sh: /bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

When I try to sudo the script I get a similar error

```
sudo: unable to execute ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

The permission on the file is as follows.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     xxxxxx     60 Dec  4 08:40 test.sh
```

Here is the content of the script

```
#!/bin/env bash
echo -e "\n\tHello from the Test Script!\n"
```

I'm pretty new at using linux so I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The first line in your script should read **#!/bin/bash**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed line 1 of the script from

```
#!/bin/env bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And I am able to run the script normally.

Thank you Bernard!

Comment: ... or use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. The `env` binary is in `/usr/bin`, not in `/bin` (usually).